# Usage of fork in a recursive function

Tags: c++, recursion, fork

I have a recursive function, in which I make a pipe. I am assuming that each function call has it's own pipe. Is that the case?

Here is my recursive function.

```
int sum(tree *&root , tree *&root2, int value1 , int value2 , int result_tree)
{
    if(root->l_child == NULL && root->r_child == NULL)
        return root->data;
    else
    {
        value1 = sum(root->l_child , root2 , value1 , value2 , result_tree);
        value2 = sum(root->r_child , root2 , value1 , value2 , result_tree);

        int fd2[2];
        pipe(fd2);
        if(fork() == 0)
        {
            if(root->data == 43)
                result_tree = value1 + value2;      
            else if(root->data == 45)
                result_tree = value1 - value2;  
            else if(root->data == 42)
                result_tree = value1 * value2;  
            else if(root->data == 47)
                result_tree = value1 / value2;  

            close(fd2[0]);
            write(fd2[1] , &result_tree , sizeof(result_tree));
        }
        else
        {
            close(fd2[1]);
            read(fd2[0] , &result_tree , sizeof(result_tree));
        }

        root->data = result_tree;
        delete_node(root2 , root);
        //cout<<"\n";
        //display_in(root2);
        return result_tree;
    }
}
```

It gives output as much times as is the number of operands in the expression.For example, if the user enters expression:  3+4+4   then the output is:  result:11result11result11

what is wrong init.

Comment: I want to know that will each recursive function call have it's own pipe.

Answer (score 1):

In response to your question

> I am assuming that each function call has it's own pipe. Is that the
>   case?

You are calling the function `pipe` once per invocation of your function `sum`. This creates a unique,anonymous,bidirectional pair of pipes. However, you are not checking the return value of `pipe`. It is possible  the pipes are not being created because you are ignoring the return value. The man page states

> On  success, zero is returned.

You should check that `pipe` returns zero when called, and abort if zero is not returned. The same goes for calls to `close`, `write`, and `read`.

If you include in your question your goal and why you think your code does not accomplish it, it is possible to provide a more informed answer. Just looking at your code, I am assuming that you understand that when the result of `fork` is zero, you are in the child process. It looks like you are writing some results to a pipe, but then you continue executing. This probably is not your intent. If it was not, you should call `exit` in the child process to terminate execution after writing to the pipe.

Comment: I got the thing you explained about storing the return value and using exit. But I just want to know that will the each function call get it's own pipe or not. Hope this explains the question.

Comment: Conceptually, yes, each level will get its own pipe.  But the function itself seems fishy in ways my non-caffeinated morning brain can not quite come to terms with.  And Eric Urban makes good points about return codes and, particularly, exiting the children.

Comment: @user2831683 The grammar in your last comment is incomprehensible.

Answer (score 0):

got the code fixed!
I just included exit(0) in child process and it's working well.

```
int sum(tree *&root , tree *&root2, int value1 , int value2 , int result_tree)
{
     if(root->l_child == NULL && root->r_child == NULL)
         return root->data;
     else
     {
         value1 = sum(root->l_child , root2 , value1 , value2 , result_tree);
         value2 = sum(root->r_child , root2 , value1 , value2 , result_tree);

         int fd2[2];
         pipe(fd2);
         if(fork() == 0)
         {
             if(root->data == 43)
                 result_tree = value1 + value2;      
             else if(root->data == 45)
                 result_tree = value1 - value2;  
             else if(root->data == 42)
                 result_tree = value1 * value2;  
             else if(root->data == 47)
                 result_tree = value1 / value2;  

             close(fd2[0]);
             write(fd2[1] , &result_tree , sizeof(result_tree));
             exit(0);                                                       // change
         }
         else
         {
             close(fd2[1]);
             read(fd2[0] , &result_tree , sizeof(result_tree));
         }

         root->data = result_tree;
         delete_node(root2 , root);
         //cout<<"\n";
         //display_in(root2);
         return result_tree;
     }
}
```

I don't understand this that what actually exit(0) did , so that the code gave correct output. Can anyone explain this exit(0) thing , in this particular piece of code. Thankyou!

Comment: There isn't much to explain.  It exits the child so you don't fall through and execute the code (not intended to be executed by the child) after the ELSE statement.  If this was the source of your problem you should accept Eric Urban's answer since he pointed it out to you.

Comment: @DUCK i pointed it from the answer of (Eric Urban), but I was not able to understand why to use exit(), in that answer. That is why I gave an answer, so that someone could explain this.